# SICP The Picture Language Exercise Lambda Argument

Tags: scheme, sicp

```
(define (segments->painter segment-list)
  (lambda (frame)
    (for-each
      (lambda (segment)
        (draw-line
          ((frame-coord-map frame)
           (start-segment segment))
          ((frame-coord-map frame)
           (end-segment segment))))
      segment-list)))
```

Some of you have already seen this sicp example before but for the first timers a brief explanation: segments->painter procedure takes arguments from segment list which has values are segments made up from vectors. for-each procedure acts like map but instead returns a list of value, it does operations like printing or in this code it draws lines. frame-coord-map scales frames according to unit square frame. What I don't understand in this code is where does first lambda function takes its argument (frame) from.

Comment: The frame argument will be passed when you invoke the function returned by calling this function, that is: `((segments->painter segment-list) frame)`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522448/how-frames-are-used-in-the-picture-language-in-sicp look Bill the Lizard's answer. You can call this code without any frame

Comment: @PyotrVanNostrand You can, of course. But calling this function *will return a function*. To call that returned function, you need a frame.

Comment: @amalloy so what's happening then if we call it without a frame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a case of [`currying`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

In your code

```
(define (segments->painter segment-list)
  (lambda (frame)
     ...))
```

when you call `segments->painter`, scheme will return an object of some *type*, let us call `figure`.  When you apply a graphical frame on this object, scheme will be able to draw your object.

```
(define obj1 (segments->painter seg1))
```

`obj1` is an object of type `figure` and this object is able to receive frames.  It is able to do only one action when it receives a frame, namely to get drawn in that frame: `(obj1 frame1)`, `(obj1 frame2)`, etc are actions you can do on that object.

Before to apply the graphical data on some object, it does make sense to talk about that object but it does not make sense to talk about a real representation of that object.  In your case, the object can do one single action: to get drawn.

Between calling the contructor for the `figure` object and drawing the object you can do some (static) preprocessing, such that in the moment when you call the drawing method, you have already precomputed something.

This is how types are implemented in programming languages.  This Peter Henderson's language is a first introduction to types and to combinators.  This will be developped further in the 4th chapter, where the interpreter uses some precomputed data to execute (it converts the list input format to internal format).

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a simpler example:

```
(define (adder x)
  (lambda (y)
    (+ x y))
```

The analogous question would be, "Where does `y` come from, if you can call `adder` with only `x`?" As discussed in the comments, it comes from whoever calls the lambda that `adder` returns. You may write:

```
(define plus5 (adder 5))
(plus5 8) ; 13
(plus5 1) ; 6
```

At the point that you call `adder`, there is no `y`. In the next call, `y` is 8, and after that it is 1.

Likewise in your actual code, there is no `frame` until someone calls the returned lambda.

Comment: (paint (segments->painter sqr-segments)) I exactly called like this with a segments-list which has four segments in it to create a square and it drew a perfect square. Still can't see any frames, what am I missing here ?

Comment: @PyotrVanNostrand The implementation of `paint` must have a frame in it somewhere, which it passes to your function.